# Extract author profile entities from Microsoft Academic API?

Tags: python, rest, academic-graph

I am working with the Microsoft Academic API to download some bibliometric data. Microsoft Academic contains just like most bibliometric databases a wide selection of entities, ranging from data on individual publications to profiles of authors and institutions.

Currently I am using this code to download relevant data for paper entities:

```
import requests
response = requests.get("https://api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/academic/v1.0/evaluate?&expr=Composite(AA.AuN==john
     smith)&count=1000&attributes=Ti&subscription-key=<subscription_key>")
```

Yet, I would like to also download "author profile" and "institution profile" data using the Microsoft Academic API, but I am not sure whether that is possible or how I can accomplish this. With "institution profile data" I mean not just the publication output of the specific institution, but rather data on where the institution is based, the total number of citations etc.

[The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/academic-services/project-academic-knowledge/reference-entity-attributes) seems to suggest that it would be possible to download data from the other entities. I have tried quite a lot of things, but to no avail, so I was wondering if someone has already managed to do this.

Comment: Do you have any code to show at all?

Comment: @Chris I didnt think that for this context the way I download data from the API is key to the solution, but I have added it nevertheless

Answer (score 1):

### Search by Author ID

For author profile data, use the author profile ID via `AA.AuId` in the `expr`-field.

Here is an example with the author profile ID `2154179079` ([Emanuel A.](https://academic.microsoft.com/author/2154179079)) with `count=30` (30 publications) showing `attributes=Ti,VFN`, that is, the title of each publication (`Ti`) and the venue's full name (`VFN`, e.g. journal name or conference name):

```
https://api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/academic/v1.0/evaluate?&expr=Composite(AA.AuId=2154179079)&count=30&attributes=AuN,Ti,VFN&subscription-key={YOUR-KEY}
```

### Search by Affiliation ID

Use the Affiliation ID via `AA.AfId` in the `expr`-field.

If you only want to find the publications from the [Hebrew University of Jerusalem](https://academic.microsoft.com/institution/197251160) (ID: `197251160`), then this would be the URL (again with 30 publications only showing titles and venues):

```
https://api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/academic/v1.0/evaluate?&expr=Composite(AA.AfId=197251160)&count=30&attributes=Ti,VFN&subscription-key={YOUR-KEY}
```

### Search by Author ID *and* Affiliation ID

To search for both author ID and affiliation ID, change the `expr` field to
`Composite(And(AA.AuId={AUTHOR-ID},AA.AfId={AFFILIATION-ID}))`.

For example, if you use the same author (Emanuel A.) from above, but only want to see the papers he published at the Hebrew University of Jerusalemn, then the `expr` field would read: `expr=Composite(And(AA.AuId=2154179079,AA.AfId=197251160))`.

The whole URL is then: 

```
https://api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/academic/v1.0/evaluate?&expr=Composite(And(AA.AuId=2154179079,AA.AfId=197251160))&count=30&attributes=Ti,VFN&subscription-key={YOUR-KEY}
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I guess that my question was a bit unclear, since I am not looking for extracting publication data that is related to a specific author or institution, but rather other relevant data on these entities such as where the institution is based etc.

Comment: Oh, I see - sorry for my misguided response then. I am likewise not aware of such a possibility. So far, all my queries to the API merely led to publication-level results.